# Comando para realizar o Down de uma migração

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Com o comando `add-migration` criei uma migração, assim é criado uma classe com duas funções.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder){...}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder){...}
```

Sei que para executar o `Up` utilizo o comando `update-database`

A pergunta é como faço para realizar o comando `Down` para desfazer a mudança que foi realizada na tabela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar o

```
Remove-Migration
```

Ele vai buscar o último Add-Migration

antes de realizar o

```
Update-Database
```

Caso já tenha utilizado o

```
Update-Database
```

Será necessário refazer as alterações criar um novo

```
Add-Migration
```

e depois rodar o

```
Update-Database
```

Friso novamente que o

```
Remove-Migration
```

só funciona quando ainda não foi realizado

```
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

Para reverter migrations você precisa executar 3 passos:

**1º passo -** Para reverter para uma determinada migration:

`Update-Database <nome-da-migration-escolhida>`

---

**2º passo -** Exclua as migrations que não deseja do projeto (serão excluídas automaticamente nas ultimas versões do VS2017)

---

**3º passo -** Use o seguinte comando para atualizar o snapshot do banco:

`Remove-Migration`